# Hide Progress Bar after Webview loaded

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-layout, progress-bar

I'm new on android studio. My problem is that the progress bar does not stop spinning after the webview finished loading.

I have also tried with this one-

```
progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //to show
        progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE); // to hide
```

But the error not resolved

My first Fragment Java Class-

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;


public class firstfragment extends Fragment{

    public WebView mywebview2;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_layout, container, false);
        mywebview2 = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.WebView);
        mywebview2.loadUrl("https://m.youtube.com");
        mywebview2.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = mywebview2.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        AdView mAdView = (AdView) v.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        return v;
    }

    public void onPageFinished(WebView view,String url){
        ProgressBar progressbar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
        progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //to show
        progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE); // to hide
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not declare this line `ProgressBar progressbar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);` inside `onPageFinished` . you have to declare it inside `onCreateView`
your code:

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView view,String url){
    ProgressBar progressbar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
    progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //to show
    progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE); // to hide
}
```

here, your `view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar2)` is referring to your `WebView` view which has nothing to do with your progressbar.

So it should be-

```
private ProgressBar progressbar;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_layout, container, false);
    mywebview2 = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.WebView);


    //here
    progressbar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
    // Enable Javascript
    WebSettings webSettings = mywebview2.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    AdView mAdView = (AdView) v.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    myWebView2.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url) {

        progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

        progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
return true;
    }
});
mywebview2.loadUrl("https://m.youtube.com");
    return v;
}
```

Comment: error- Method does not override from its superclass.

Comment: Error-  onPageStarted() in WebViewClient cannot be applied.

Comment: Please don't waste my time and also your if you don't know the answer. errors are still maintained.

Answer (score 1):

public class firstfragment extends Fragment {

```
    public WebView mywebview2;
    private ProgressBar progressbar;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_layout, container, false);
        mywebview2 = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.WebView);
        mywebview2.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        progressbar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);

        // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = mywebview2.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mywebview2.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
        mywebview2.loadUrl("https://m.youtube.com");
        AdView mAdView = (AdView) v.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear friend it doesn't work. Same problem still persist.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
{
   super.onPageFinished(view, url);
   progressBar.setVisibility(view.GONE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this with below code you can load progress as per data load in web view and after page loading progress bar hide

```
    String url = "";
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.loadUrl(url);
         progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);


        progressBar.setMax(100);
        progressBar.setProgress(1);


        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                progressBar.setProgress(progress);
            }
        });
 webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            }



            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
//                progressDialog.hide();
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

    }
```

**layout file**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_web_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_marginTop="-7dp"
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="1"
        android:theme="@style/ProgressbarTheme" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**ask me in case of any query**

Comment: where to add this ? please suggest full code. I'm new on android studio.

Comment: @SunilBisu add this code in your  `onCreate()` method

Comment: Error found -1. Cannot resolve symbol - tvUrl , 2.Cannot resolve symbol - url ,3.Cannot resolve symbol - tvTitle , and 4. Missing return statement

Comment: ignore that line it for my case

Comment: Error:(74, 6) error: reached end of file while parsing

Comment: Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
C:\Users\Karim Bux\Chhotu Ram\Desktop\SUNIL\Android App Project\HanumanBeniwal5\app\src\main\java\com\hanumanbeniwal\www\hanumanbeniwal\firstfragment.java
Error:(74, 6) error: reached end of file while parsing
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 4.777 secs
Information:2 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console

Comment: Error:(31, 24) error: cannot find symbol class progressbar
Error:(31, 56) error: cannot find symbol variable progressBar
Error:(32, 23) error: cannot find symbol variable url
Error:(32, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable tvUrl
Error:(33, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable tvTitle
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: add progressBar control in your layout

Comment: Everything is ok but one error still persist - Error:(68, 5) error: missing return statement
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: helpmebit.sikar@gmail.com